# ideavim how to close command-prompt after running :marks or :reg

Tags: ideavim

I'm having this weird issue with AppCode IdeaVim plugin. After installing it everything seems to work correctly. However I am experiencing some really annoying thing. Whenever I try to list the marks by running the `:marks` command or `:registers` they are listed, screenshot of the command-prompt:

[image: screenshot of the command-prompt]

but I cannot close the command prompt. It says `Hit ENTER or type command`, but hitting Enter does not close it, neither does entering other command.

Normally in vim after pressing `esc` the command prompt is closed. So I thought it might be by design. Or I am missing some shortcut key?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

By default the keys are `(RET: line, SPACE: page, d: half page, q: quit)`, from https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/f33f73d2f5f89d9ff50c336dcd75e2ef13db0c33/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/ui/ExOutputPanel.java#L282-L331

The problem is by default the key listener is added to the **command prompt**.

But after you type something like `:marks`, the focus is still in the editor. You can verify it by typing `j`, the editor still scrolls.

Of course the command prompt does not know what you type or do any actions.

At least now, there is no better way than first manually click the command prompt, then you can type the shortcuts you like.

Comment: That is very annoying, and counter to the purpose of IdeaVIM. Hopefully a solution is found or developed.